# jquery Carousel problem

Tags: jquery, carousel

i have this script found here http://jsfiddle.net/g4txt/
i am using this carousel http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

the problem is that it won't show all images.

the script is running, in the way that is scrolling through images but it wont show them all

try adding and deleting `li`'s and you will notice the problem

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

First: your img tags need to be closed.

Second: $(function(){ ... } is the same as $(document).ready(function(){ ... } and is therefore redundant.

Third: if you float your li's left, you'll be all set.

Cheers

Comment: u are a genius.. :) i didn't see that in the script